# Homeomorphism between sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $$ Y = \left\{ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}\cup\left\{ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$ and
$$ X = \left\{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} $$ be subspaces of the Euclidean space $ \mathbb{R} $.
Are $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic (i.e., does there exist a continuous bijection between them whose inverse function is continuous)?
I tried to construct a bijection, but, every time I try, I can't get it to be continuous.
So I would assume that they are not homeomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

Your topologies are discrete, so every map is continuous. Therefore every bijection between $\mathbb{Z}^*$ and $\mathbb{N}$ will do.

Comment: Yes, a more interesting question would be if $X'$ and $Y'$ are homeomorphic where $X'=X\cup\{0\}$ and $Y'=Y\cup\{\frac{1}{2}\}$. I believe it also is true in that case.

Comment: Do you mean to say that every bijection between $Y$ and $X$ will do?

Comment: @FlorisClaassens Yes, you just need to make sure that $0$ is mapped to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Well yes, but $Y$ is just like $\mathbb{Z}^*$ and $X$ is just like $\mathbb{N}$, so every bijection between $\mathbb{Z}^*$ and $\mathbb{N}$ induces a bijection between $Y$ and $X$.

Comment: I understood that, but it seemed a bit cryptic when compared to the notation in the question.

Comment: @LeeMosher Fair enough, thanks for pointing it out.